# Set equal width in flex but different with other childs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What I'm trying to do is, make a view exactly like `table` but with `div` what I did, use `flex` and `calc()` to make equal width between rows but first row should has different width (bigger than other) for this I used `100%/1` it working when it is empty but when it has content, not working anymore. See below example:

```css
.tr {
    display: flex;
}

.tr .th,.tr .td {
    width: calc(100%/5);
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.tr .th:first-child, .tr .td:first-child {
    width: calc(100%/1);
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tr">
  <div class="th">T</div>
  <div class="th">T</div>
  <div class="th">T</div>
  <div class="th">T</div>
  <div class="th">T</div>
</div>

<div class="tr">
  <div class="td">Bdddddddddddddddd    22323 23 </div>
  <div class="td">Bdddddd</div>
  <div class="td">Bdddddddddddd</div>
  <div class="td">Bdd</div>
  <div class="td">Bdddddddddddddd asd</div>
</div>
```

What I want to set equal `width` for all rows but first rows should has equal width but longer than other. In above example, as you see rows not equal.

Comment: min-width:0 to all the divs

Comment: @TemaniAfif `min-width:0` not solve my problem

Comment: @TemaniAfif Test it then close the topic!

Comment: I already tested (https://jsfiddle.net/2vxyrgbo/), this is not what you want? if no, then add more details about the layout you want

Comment: or probably you want it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/2vxyrgbo/2/ (I can add another duplicate for this too)

Comment: Another simple solution would be to change the (100%/5) to (100%/2.5) and  change the (100%/1) to (100%/1.5)